# Line in product mainifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M_1, g_1)$ and $(M_2, g_2)$  be two complete Riemannian manifolds and consider the product $(M, g) = (M_1 \times M_2, g_1 + g_2)$.

Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to (M,g )$ be a line. I can write $t \mapsto \gamma(t) = ( \gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))$, where $\gamma_1(t) \in M_1$ and $\gamma_2(t) \in M_2$.

I know that if $\gamma$ is a geodesic then also $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are geodesics in $(M_1, g_1)$ and $(M_2, g_2)$  respectively.

My question is

> If $\gamma$ is a *line*, how can I prove that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are lines (assuming that they are not constant and up to a scaling factor)?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Let $(N, g_N)$ be a Riemannian manifold. A geodesic $l : \mathbb{R} \to (N, g_N)$ is said to be a *line* if 
$$
dist\big(l(s), l(t)\big) = |t-s|
$$
for every $t, s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean by line?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I edited the question adding the deifinition of line. Thank you for your question. I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c(t)=(c_1,c_2)(t),\ t\in [0,1]$ is a curve in the product
manifold then we have that $c$ is geodesic iff $c_1,\ c_2$ are
geodesic

And we have length $$ L(c)=\int_0^1 \sqrt{ |c_1'(t)|_{g_1}^2+
|c_2'(t)|_{g_2}^2 }\ dt
$$

For $(p_1,q_1), \ (p_2,q_2)$ there exists a shortest geodesic $c
:[0,1]\rightarrow M_1\times M_2 $ by $c(t)=(c_1,c_2)(t)$ Then $$
d((p_1,q_1),  (p_2,q_2))=L(c)= \int_0^1 \sqrt{ |c_1'(t)|_{g_1}^2+
|c_2'(t)|_{g_2}^2 }\ dt  =\sqrt{ |c_1'(0)|_{g_1}^2 +
|c_2'(0)|_{g_2}^2}$$

If $c_1$ is not a shortest geodesic from $p_1$ to $p_2$, then there
exists a shortest geodesic $a$ s.t. $$ a: [0,1]\rightarrow M_1,\
|a'(0)|_{g_1} < |c_1'(0)|_{g_1} $$

This implies that $c$ is not shortest.